# How to beat the fourth boss in Castlevania: Spectral Interlude for ZX Spectrum?

Tags: castlevania-spectral-interlude

I'm playing [Castlevania: Spectral Interlude](https://zxonline.net/game/castlevania-spectral-interlude/) for [ZX Spectrum 128K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum#ZX_Spectrum_128), but I found the fourth boss released after putting the green altar in place to be ridiculously hard. Is there any good strategy to beat it?

Comment: I could look it up on youtube, but I don't care to watch the whole video to figure out which boss is the fourth one--what does this boss look like?

Comment: @Exal The available playthrough on youtube is not very helpful because the boss in the video has a different behavior compared to the version I'm playing. It looks like a snake spawning little snakes.

Answer (score 3):

Every video fighting Medusa I can find uses a battle of attrition technique.  Taking a relatively safe position either kneeling on the (left only?) side of the water or on the left edge of the platform and continually whipping away snakes, only hitting Medusa when she teleports to a position directly in front of you.  You'll have to double-jump away when she teleports to your area, but (especially if you're on the top platform and can do it without touching the ground) you can reestablish your position and continue your whipping.  Good luck!

Comment: If I kneeling on the left side of the water the boss teleports behind my back and throws me in the water. The same for the right side.